# Access a variable in my App component globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I have a `boolean` held in state which is used to determine a `reference` array, which will be used throughout my project:

```
function App() {

// State used throughout the whole application to decide if it should
// display sharp or flat symbols
const [isSharp, setIsSharp] = React.useState(false)

const reference: string[] = ['Ab', 'A', 'Bb', 'B', 'C', 'Db', 'D', 'Eb', 'E', 'F', 'Gb', 'G'];
if (isSharp) {
    const reference: string[] = ['G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G'];
}
```

I have a separate file which I'd like to keep my JS functions in (that don't use React). Currently, this is in there:

```
function numToLet(input: number | number[]): string | string[] {

if (typeof input === 'number') {
    return reference[input];
}

return input.map(item => numToLet(item));
```

In this function, I'd like to use the `reference` array, but I cannot access it.

The first solution I can think of is to pass the `boolean` into the function as an argument, then determine the `reference` array within it. However, I plan on using the `reference` array elsewhere in my code, so I don't want code redundancy by needing to define it in two places.

How could I get my function to see the `reference` variable, without needing to add additional arguments to my function?

Side note: I need to be able to call the `numToLet()` function inside of my App.tsx file aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that and tweak a little bit your code like this:

App.tsx

```
export const AppContext = createContext({
  isSharp: true,
  toggle: () => {},
  reference: [] // or the default array you want to access
});

export const App = () => {
  const [isSharp, setIsSharp] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const reference = useMemo(() => {
    if (isSharp) return // the isSharp array
    else return // the other array
  }, [isSharp]);
  
  const toggle = () => setIsSharp((prevState) => !prevState);
  
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ isSharp, toggle, reference }}>
      {/* Your App JSX Content */}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

after that wrap your `numToLet` function in a custom hook (which may gather other functions aswell).

useNumToLet.ts

```
import { AppContext } from './App.tsx';

export const useNumToLet = () => {
  // use the context here
  const { reference } = useContext(AppContext);

  const numToLet = (input: number | number[]): string | string[] {
    if (typeof input === 'number') return reference[input];
    return input.map(item => numToLet(item));
  }

  return { numToLet };
}
```

now where ever you want to access that function you can just call it.

```
export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { numToLet } = useNumToLet();
  
  return (
    <SomeJSX />
  )
}
```

Generally I suggest to wrap all your frontend logic in some kind of custom hook in order to access your app state. If you want to avoid it (for some reason) you could pass the return value of that function as parameter to another plain JS function.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to read up on context. Thanks!